# Multicollinearity in structural equation modeling with multiple imputation?

Tags: r, multicollinearity, structural-equation-modeling, multiple-imputation

Using R, I created a structural equation model and fit it to multiple datasets using the 'sem.mi()' function from the SemTools package. I know multicollinearity tends to be a concern for structural equation models, and the usual way to check it is through the VIF and/or tolerance values.

But the VIF functions I am familiar with (e.g. 'car::vif()') don't work with lavaan.mi objects. Is there another way I could check for multicollinearity? (Also, is this even a relevant concern? I know there are some situations in which multicollinearity doesn't affect results in a significant way, so if I am incorrect in my concerns here, I would appreciate any references you could direct me to about this).

Thanks!

Comment: I think (but am not certain) that you could check for multicolinearity on either the complete data or on any single imputed data set.